# jQuery councurent coding issue (Synchronous jQuery)

Tags: jquery, parallel-processing, iteration

By not going through all jQuery function's i had a problem with jQuery since i started using it.

The problem with it is that some function's it executes in a parallel way.

If i had an `<ol>` with 100 `<li>` childrens.

When im trying to itterate through all li items and increment a counter than display the counter proper value it fails.

```
​$(document).ready(function(){
    var counter = 0;        
    $("ul li").each(function(){
      counter++;              
    });
    $("div").text(counter);
});​
```

Counter on div text is always 0

Is there a way to control the way how function's are executed parallel or not-parallel (Synchronous or Asynchronous).

Here's the code on jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/burimshala/pf6pn/

Comment: Did you try iterating over the correct elements -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pf6pn/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looping through `UL LI` not `OL LI`.

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pf6pn/2/

With that in mind, change:

```
$("ul li").each(function(){
```

to

```
$("ol li").each(function(){
```